# JS replacement for global variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For my voice recorder app, I'm looking for a possibility to change implementation of global variable 'recorder'. As it is commonly known global variables aren't recommended. Can it be done differently?

```
var recorder;
export default function AddAudio() {

    const Start = async () => {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
            .then((stream) => {
                recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
                recorder.start();
                let chunks = [];
                recorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", event => {
                    chunks.push(event.data);
                });

                recorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
                    const blob = new Blob(chunks);
                });
            })
    }
    const Stop = () => {
        recorder.stop();
    };
```

Comment: Move the variable to inside the AddAudio?

Comment: It doesn't work. When I click on Stop it tells me that I can't read properties of undefined.

Comment: unsure how that would be possible. Did you move it into Start by accident? `export default function AddAudio() {  let recorder;`

Comment: @100domino: Did you successfully *start* before doing that?  In your debugging, was `recorder` ever successfully set to a value?  Please provide an example of the problem.

Comment: Best solution would probably move over to a class structure.

Comment: if it's moved by one line under AddAudio it doesn't work. When I click Start function it reads variable properly, but when I click on Stop it doen't take updated value from Start  (recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream)) which I'd like to obtain

Answer (score 2):

Put it inside the function

```
export default function AddAudio() {
    let recorder;
    const Start = async () => {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
            .then((stream) => {
                recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
                recorder.start();
                let chunks = [];
                recorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", event => {
                    chunks.push(event.data);
                });

                recorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
                    const blob = new Blob(chunks);
                });
            })
    }
    const Stop = () => {
        recorder.stop();
    };
}
```

P.S.

Don't use `var` please

Comment: Also, make sure the `recorder` is defined (has some value) before calling the `recorder.stop()`. You may write something like `recorder?.stop()`

Comment: I would expect an error if I would try to call `stop` before initialization. Depends on the use case.

Comment: @Obie, `recorder` has a value as it is updated in Start function. However this value is not passed to  `recorder.stop()` (`recorder` is undefined)